# closedxml sorting by specific number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, closedxml

I have a problem with ClosedXML in C#. I want to sort data but I want the system read column have numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4 and then sort by that.

If I use `ws.Sort(1)` the title is sorted too.

Here's my code:

```
protected void ImportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Save the uploaded Excel file.
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);

//Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(filePath))
{
    //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
    IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

    //Create a new DataTable.
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    workSheet.sort(1);
    //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
    bool firstRow = true;
    foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
    {
        //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
        if (firstRow)
        {
            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
            }
            firstRow = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Add rows to DataTable.
            dt.Rows.Add();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                i++;
            }
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

is there anyway to sort with specific column with number ?

Comment: share your excel file dat and define what you want to sort. Your question is not clear

Comment: sorry here the link [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BylPwgnUi43VZzRzdFZZSHdpMFE)

Comment: cannot open your link. share it as a picture/some other format and mention which column you want to sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the range of cells that you want to sort, but exclude the headers and call the `IXLRange.Sort()` method, rather than the `IXLWorksheet.Sort()` method.

Example:

```
var range = wb.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A2:C6");
range.Sort(1);
```

Comment: thanks it work  but the title is sorted too anyway to not short that or delete the title ?

Comment: Log an issue in the github page with short code sample that reproduce either problem. Attach the file too.